# UV Preconditioning test

Tags: energy, solar-cells, scaling

I wanna build a solar panel with a new material and I wanna to test the endurance of the material against UV light. I've found in internet a Standard for UV tests. It says it has to be irradiated with 15kwh/m² from 280nm to 385nm. Since I just have a 8w UV lamp I decided to do some scaling to the test. Instead of 1m² I made an small sample of 100cm². To get the same energy in this surface I calculate that it must be at least 18hours under 8w UV light. Am I right? If not, please show me how to do it. 
Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to round to the nearest hour, round up. I get 19 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Does your 8W lamp put out 8W of light in that band of wavelengths? or does it use 8W of electricity? With most lamps, the Wattage rating tells you how much electricity it uses, which can be much greater than the amount of optical power that it puts out. That becomes even more of a concern if you are only interested in that fraction of the optical power that falls within a narrow band of wavelengths.

Also, if your lamp is only putting out 8W of optical power, it's going to be nearly impossible to get 100% of that light to evenly irradiate the target. Depending on the geometry of your optical system, it's likely that some, or a lot, of the total power emitted by the lamp will be absorbed by other surfaces in your test fixture.

Comment: Hello Salomon. You're totally right. I know that the electrical power energy in the bulb (8w) it's not the same energy that irradiates. It's only for testing purposes, I just wanna to test as closest as possible as in the stardar test. how can I calculate the energy radiated by the lamp?

Comment: If you can get a _[data sheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datasheet)_ for the lamp, you might find the answer there. Otherwise, I don't know what else you can do but measure its output. I do not know what tools or techniques you can use to measure those wavelengths. Might not be cheap.